# Concatenate strings after variable replacing strings

Tags: bash, variable

I have below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat list.txt | while IFS='' read -r a; 
#Remove all illegal characters
do
   a=${a//  /_}
   a=${a// /_}
   a=${a//\'/}
   a=${a//-/_}
   a=${a,,}
   filepath="/applications/"
   b=$filepath$a".csv"
   echo $b
done
```

The expected results should be:

```
/applications/ahold_region
/applications/alb_sfy_region
/applications/awg_census_region
/applications/bjs_total_ta
/applications/delhaize_region
/applications/dollar_value_area
```

The real results are:

```
.csvlications/ahold_region
.csvlications/alb_sfy_region
.csvlications/awg_census_region
.csvlications/bjs_total_ta
.csvlications/delhaize_region
.csvlications/dollar_value_area
```

It looks like bash is using `.csv` to replace the first 4 characters in `$filepath`.

How to generate the expected results?

Comment: You have Windows-style CRLF line endings in the file. The CR gets left in, before you add the `.csv` and it moves the cursor to the beginning of line when printing.

Comment: @ilkkachu I have changed to Linux line end (LF) and still got the same results.

Comment: @lovechillcool, did you remove the CRs from both the list.txt file and your script file?

Comment: @glennjackman, it's not the script, a CR at the end where, say the `do` keyword was expected, would cause a syntax error (the shell would see `do\r` instead)

Comment: Kindly post list.txt content

Comment: @glennjackman Good point, Glenn, I didn't remove the CR from list.txt. Now the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have `CRLF` not only in the script but also in the `list.txt`. After I changed to `LF` in both shell and `list.txt`, the issue is resolved.